# how to fill the area under a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, fill

I can not find a way to fill the area **under** these 3 curves and the legend doesn't seem to show the correct line colours (the red one is missing?). Thanks.
[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,clip=false,
      xmin=-1,xmax=5,
      ymin=-1,ymax=5,
      ticks=none,
      %axis line style={draw=none},
      tick style={draw=none},
      legend pos=outer north east,
      scale=1.7
      ]

\addplot[no marks,color=gray!20,fill=gray!20,domain=0:4,samples=200] {4} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,color=blue!20,fill=blue!20,domain=-0:3.3,samples=200,scale=0.3,transform canvas={rotate around={22:(0,4)}},color=gray]plot[smooth] {-sqrt(x)+4-0.2*sin(deg(x^2))} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,color=lime!20,fill=lime!20,domain=0:4.95,samples=200,transform canvas={rotate around={37:(0,0)}},scale=0.3,color=blue] plot[smooth]{0.75*sin(deg(x^2))/x} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,domain=1.5:4.05,samples,scale=0.3,transform canvas={rotate around={15:(1.5,0)}},color=red] plot[smooth]{0.5*sin(deg((x-1.5)*(x-1.5)))/(x-1.5)};
\node at (axis cs:1,1) {$\Omega_1$};
\node at (axis cs:1,2.5) {$\Omega_2$};
\node at (axis cs:1.3,3.6) {$\Omega_3$};
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw (0,4) node[left]{$b$} ;
\draw (0,0) node[below]{$t_0$} ;
\draw (0,0) node[above left]{$1$} ;
\draw (4,0) node[below]{$t_1$} ;
\draw (2.21,0.6) node[below] {$(\tau,\sigma)$}  node[color=red] {$\times$};
 \draw (1.5,0) node[below] {$\xi^{\tau}(\sigma)$}  node[rotate=41,color=red] {$>$};
\draw [blue] (4,3.3) node[above right] {$\Phi_{(t_0,1)}$};
\draw [red] (4,1.1) node[below right] {$\Phi_{(\tau,\sigma)}$};
\draw [gray] (3.7,4) node[above] {$\Phi_{(t_0,b)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(t_0,b)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(t_0,1)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(\tau,\sigma)}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Which curves do you want to get filled. (The `fillbetween` library allows you to fill pretty much any curve.)

Comment: Gray between {y=4} and {y=sqrt{x}+4-0.2*\sin{x^2)}, lime between {y=sqrt{x}+4-0.2*sin{x^2)} and {y=0.75*sin(x^2)/x}, blue between {y=0.75*sin(x^2)/x} and {y-0}

Comment: A large fraction of the difficulties stems from you using `transform canvas`. Have you tried to produce the plots without it (and e.g. just using `rotate around` or changing the parametrization of the plots)?

Comment: I used rotate around and fillbetween but the problem still.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what your target picture is. And I am not claiming that the additional terms I add precisely correspond to your `rotate around` statements (but to a low approximation they do). Anyway, I am wondering if the following goes in the right direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} %<- for more delicate fills
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,clip=false,
      xmin=-1,xmax=5,
      ymin=-1,ymax=5,
      ticks=none,
      %axis line style={draw=none},
      tick style={draw=none},
      legend pos=outer north east,
      scale=1.7
      ]

\addplot[no marks,color=gray!20,fill=gray!20,domain=0:4,samples=2,forget plot] {4} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,color=blue!20,fill=blue!20,domain=-0:4,samples=200,%scale=0.3,
%rotate around={22:(0,4)},
color=gray]  {-sqrt(x)+4-0.2*sin(deg(x^2))+tan(22)*x} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,color=lime!20,fill=lime!20,domain=0:4,samples=200,
%rotate around={37:(0,0)},scale=0.3,
color=blue] 
{0.75*sin(deg(x^2))/x+tan(37)*x} \closedcycle;

\addplot[no marks,domain=1.5:4,samples,%scale=0.3,rotate around={15:(1.5,0)},
color=red,fill=red] {0.5*sin(deg((x-1.5)*(x-1.5)))/(x-1.5)+tan(15)*x}
\closedcycle;
\node at (axis cs:1,1) {$\Omega_1$};
\node at (axis cs:1,2.5) {$\Omega_2$};
\node at (axis cs:1.3,3.6) {$\Omega_3$};
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw (0,4) node[left]{$b$} ;
\draw (0,0) node[below]{$t_0$} ;
\draw (0,0) node[above left]{$1$} ;
\draw (4,0) node[below]{$t_1$} ;
\draw (2.21,0.6) node[below] {$(\tau,\sigma)$}  node[color=red] {$\times$};
 \draw (1.5,0) node[below] {$\xi^{\tau}(\sigma)$}  node[rotate=41,color=red] {$>$};
\draw [blue] (4,3.3) node[above right] {$\Phi_{(t_0,1)}$};
\draw [red] (4,1.1) node[below right] {$\Phi_{(\tau,\sigma)}$};
\draw [gray] (3.7,4) node[above] {$\Phi_{(t_0,b)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(t_0,b)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(t_0,1)}$};
\addlegendentry{$\Phi_{(\tau,\sigma)}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]